# Adequacy of cross-validation in a image classification problem

Tags: classification, cross-validation, image-processing, hyperparameter, image-segmentation

The problem I am facing is remote sensing image classification. My initial idea was to perform feature selection, classifier selection and hyperparameter tuning inside cross-validation inner loop, following the recommendations that I have [read](https://www.nodalpoint.com/not-perform-feature-selection/). As far as I know, this is the safest way to perform said process, but in my case, it presents two problems:

- I intended to employ image textures (i.e. GLCM) which have to be calculated for each band of each acquisition, which causes the data volume to inflate to an unmanageable volume (9 bands * 12 acquisitions * > 10 Haralick textures). There is a way to first select the relevant bands, and afterwards, calculate the textures only for those bands?

[image: Example of texture application]

- I also wanted to compare whether object-based image classification could improve the results. For this, I would need to segment the image, creating groups of pixels with their features (pixel and shape statistics, etc.), and perform the process for said groups. How fair would be the comparison with the classification performed at pixel level?

[image: Example of pixel vs object-based image classification]